# Find all combination that sum to N when multiplies by index

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

Given a number of items (*n*), what is the most efficient way to generate all possible lists [a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>] of non-negative integers under the condition that:

1*a<sub>1</sub> + 2*a<sub>2</sub> + 3*a<sub>3</sub> + ... + n*a<sub>n</sub> = n

using Python?

So for example, given an n of 5, the following combinations are:

[0,0,0,0,1]

[1,0,0,1,0]

[0,1,1,0,0]

[2,0,1,0,0]

[1,2,0,0,0]

[3,1,0,0,0]

[5,0,0,0,0]

I've implemented a brute-force method that generates all permutations and then checks if the list meets the above requirement, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @idjaw: There is an actual problem (i.e. efficiency). My understanding is that [efficiency questions are valid on Stack overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215282/is-stack-overflow-the-right-place-to-ask-a-question-about-code-efficiency).

Comment: I edited the start of the question to make it clearer.  Note that it's often the case for questions about combinatorial generation that showing brute-force code is useless:  it's both obvious and unhelpful.  Happy to take the OP at their word that "I've implemented a brute-force method that generates all permutations and then checks if the list meets the above requirement", and am glad they didn't bother to show it ;-)  Efficient code (which they're asking about) in this area often has approximately nothing to do with brute-force code that merely works.

Answer (score 2):

A "greedy" algorithm works well for this.  I'm using Python 3 here:

```
def pick(total):

    def inner(highest, total):
        if total == 0:
            yield result
            return
        if highest == 1:
            result[0] = total
            yield result
            result[0] = 0
            return
        for i in reversed(range(total // highest + 1)):
            result[highest - 1] = i
            newtotal = total - i * highest
            yield from inner(min(highest - 1, newtotal),
                             newtotal)

    result = [0] * total
    yield from inner(total, total)
```

Then, e.g.,

```
for x in pick(5):
    print(x)
```

displays:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Like most recursive algorithms, it does a more-or-less obvious thing, then recurses to solve the (sub)problem that remains.

Here `inner(highest, total)` means to find all the decompositions of `total` using integers no larger than `highest`.  How many copies of `highest` can we use?  The more-than-less obvious answer is that we can use 0, 1, 2, ..., up to (and including) `total // highest` copies, but no more than that.  Unless `highest` is 1 - then we have to use exactly `total` copies of 1.

However many copies we use of `highest`, the subproblem remaining is to decompose whatever remains of the total using integers no larger than `highest - 1`.  Passing `min(highest - 1, newtotal)` instead of `highest - 1` is an optimization, since it's pointless trying any integer larger than the new total.